# Plugin [id: 'com.github.ben-manes.versions'] was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: gradle

Here is my gradle build file and getting the following error:-

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java Library project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Libraries chapter in the Gradle
 * user guide available at https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/java_library_plugin.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
    id 'java-library'
    id 'de.fuerstenau.buildconfig' version '1.1.8' apply true
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'com.github.ben-manes.versions' version '$version'
    id 'com.palantir.git-version'
}

dependencies {
    classpath(
        "gradle.plugin.com.palantir.gradle.gitversion:gradle-git-version:0.5.3",
        "com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.13.0",
        "gradle.plugin.de.fuerstenau:BuildConfigPlugin:1.1.4",
        "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.13",
        "com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3",
     )
    compile(
      "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$versions.okhttp",
      "com.google.code.gson:gson:$versions.gson",
    )

    compileOnly(
      "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:$versions.autoValue",
      deps.nullityAnnotations,
      "com.github.kevinmost.auto-value-custom-hashcode-equals:adapter:$versions.customHashCodeEquals",
        )

    apt(
      "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:$versions.autoValue",
      "com.gabrielittner.auto.value:auto-value-with:1.0.0",
      "com.github.kevinmost.auto-value-custom-hashcode-equals:processor:$versions.customHashCodeEquals",
    )

    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()    
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

buildConfig {
  packageName = "api2"
  clsName = "BuildConfig"
}

 ext.versions = [
      okhttp: "3.4.1",
      gson: "2.7",
      autoValue: "1.5.2",
      slf4j: "1.7.21",
      kotlin: "1.0.5-2",

      customHashCodeEquals: "db3442d",
  ]
```

Error:_

```
* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.github.ben-manes.versions'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)
```

Comment: see my answer: I suspect that error comes from your invalid version declaration for this plugin : `version '$version'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plugins` DSL has some limitations described here [Plugins DSL - Constraine syntax](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:constrained_syntax): you cannot use variables to set the version.

> The form is:
>
> `plugins {
>        id «plugin id» version «plugin version» [apply «false»]
>   }`
>
> Where «plugin id» and «plugin version» **must be constant, literal, strings**

You should apply this plugin as follows:

```
plugins {
    id "com.github.ben-manes.versions" version "0.20.0"
}
```